# Replace modal image on Click

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

It's been a while since I used JS and I'm getting problems creating this modal-img.

I'm following [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp) guide.

The modal script is working as it should. If I click on the image "img_snow.jpg" it opens the modal with the same image, but what I really need is to click on the image and open the modal with a different image "img_fire.jpg", not the same one I previously clicked on.

I'm trying to replace "img_snow.jpg" with "img_fire.jpg" ONLY when the modal pops up.

Any clue about how to solve this?

```
<!-- Image to show on the modal -->
<img id="myImgToReplace" src="img_fire.jpg">

<!-- Trigger the Modal -->
<img id="myImg" src="img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- The Close Button -->
  <span class="close">&times;</span>

  <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">

  <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: insert your html

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov sure!

Comment: Are you using exactly the same code as in the example from the source? Then your problem is not clear. Please explain specifically your problem again.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov I edited the post, is it clear now?

Comment: those, in the preview should be - img_snow.jpg, and in the modal window itself img_fire.jpg?

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov Exactly!

Comment: I gave an answer and an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the desired result, you need to modify the event function `img.onclick = function(){}`.

Declare a variable to which you want to put the default image (preview):

```
let default_image = this.src;
```

For this.src you need to assign the image path for the modal window (I chose a random picture):

```
this.src = 'https://www.12542.ru/206-28.jpg';
```

And in order for the default picture to return, you need to do this

```
this.src = default_image;
```

In the end, your function should be like this:

```
img.onclick = function(){
  let default_image = this.src;
  modal.style.display = "block";
  this.src = 'https://www.12542.ru/206-28.jpg';
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  this.src = default_image;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}
```

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
  let default_image = this.src;
  modal.style.display = "block";
  this.src = 'https://www.12542.ru/206-28.jpg';
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  this.src = default_image;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {  
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
  to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform:scale(0)} 
  to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="myImg" src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/big0/98/Slovenia_Summer_Lake_487816.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

second solution:

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var img = document.querySelectorAll(".myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

const img_modal = ['https://static3.depositphotos.com/1000992/133/i/600/depositphotos_1337508-stock-photo-a-free-flying-white-dove.jpg',
'https://i.pinimg.com/474x/9c/a1/7e/9ca17e8e343e1ebfee9a463fc4ec22fe.jpg', 
'https://everskate.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/how-to-kickflip-trick-tip-600x336.jpg'];

Array.from(img).forEach(function(imgArray, i) {
  imgArray.onclick = function(){
    let default_image = this.src;
    modal.style.display = "block";
    this.src = img_modal[i];
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    this.src = default_image;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
  }
});


var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {  
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
  to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform:scale(0)} 
  to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="myImg" src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/big0/98/Slovenia_Summer_Lake_487816.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">

<img class="myImg" src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/big0/235/Poppies_Summer_Grasslands_Trees_562184_1270x1024.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">

<img class="myImg" src="https://akiwa.ru/upload/dev2fun_opengraph/ccf/ccf8acce0f0bdabc13d15f4f1ff6c549.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's great! I understand it! Now... what should I do if I want to use multiple images with the same script? Should I declare different variables instead of using this.src? How?

Comment: Yes, several are possible, but for this you need the `forEach` method, and you need to edit function `img.onclick = function(){...}`.

Comment: Great Sergey! Could you please paste where should I write it? Sorry, my JS is clearly more than rusty :/

Comment: If I have time today, I will write you a code for several images.

Comment: Is your problem relevant at the moment?

Comment: Yes! I'm still trying to figure this out but I don't know how to apply the forEach to my code :(

Comment: I added a second solution (second snippet). I did it using forEach, declaring an array with pictures for the modal window. Note that id myImg is now a class, as there can only be one id.

Answer (score 0):

```
  modalImg.src = document.getElementById('myImgToReplace').src;
```

did you tried this ?

Comment: Yes, it's working as well, but I need to implement this for multiple images.

Comment: I can't understand your senario.